# Can the unitsOneEthCanBuy value be changed after Token creation?

Tags: tokens, dapps, cpp-ethereum

How can I change the value of "unitsOneEthCanBuy" in the contract ? 
 (As the Token is only created & ICO has n't happened)

Comment: Voting to close this question as it lacks discussion context and is thus impossible to answer. Furthermore it is three questions in one. I recommend asking exact one questions per question, with necesarry background details and information to make questions answerable.

Comment: As i m new here, didn't know the rules here. Edited now. Thank U.

Comment: The question still lacks the context, like source code, projects, etc. discussed. You can set variable in Solidity with assign `=` operator. Otherwise I cannot give further direction in this point.